# How to Create a "Mixed" Network Science Graph

Tags: graphs-and-networks, networking

I am trying to create a network science graph from "mixed" data. What I mean is that the data has different units. For example this social network only contains friends:

[image: A simple network of friends and their connections]

But what if I wanted a network that includes places that friends live in or something like that in addition to people. Just a network that contains multiple units of measurement. Is there a way to form this network?

Comment: By "multiple units of measurements" you mean "different types of edges between nodes"?

Comment: You might be interested in the term "heterogeneous graph". Also, depending on what you're trying to do, `EntityStore` might be closer to what you want.

Comment: @yohbs I mean different types of nodes themselves. The edges might be different but that's not what I'm targeting.

Comment: @MichaelCurry I will do some research on it, thanks for your help!